# Upgraded a retina SSD, now I get random crashes/shutdowns with code 3. Why?

Tags: ssd, crash, shutdown

I recently upgraded an early-2015 13" Macbook Pro (A1502) from a 128GB SSD to a 256GB ssd. I used Carbon Copy Cloner to clone the original drive to an external 500GB, then booted off of that and cloned to the 256GB SSD.

Now, random shutdowns are happening, and upon logging back in I get a "you shut your computer down because of a problem" message.

The output of `log show --predicate 'eventMessage contains "Previous shutdown cause"' --last 24h` is as follows:

[image]
As you can see, I'm getting the shutdown cause of 3 consistently. With some research, I figured out this is the code for a "forced shutdown" (e.g. pressing and holding the power button), but it is crashing all by itself. It seems to happen consistently if I leave the laptop idle, and let it go to sleep. It seems to crash when it sleeps.

Where should I begin debugging this? Is my new SSD defective somehow? Or is this a software issue that could be fixed by reinstalling macOS? Is there anything I should check before I reinstall the OS?

Thanks for any help here!

Comment: Have you tried resetting the SMC and NVRAM since the swap? Sometimes that helps

Comment: I had a similar issue when replacing my HDD with an SSD on an older MacBook Pro. I was able to fix it by updating the SSD's firmware. Have you contacted the SSD manufacturer to check if they have newer firmware or drivers?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @NoahL - I tried that. And I replaced it with a genuine used Apple SSD.